# BgColor of navbar not changing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I really don´t know why I can´t change the navbar´s color. I tried everything from making a specific ID to styling the whole navbar element. I´m sorry if this question sounds stupid but I don´t know what to do.

Css:

```
navbar {
    background-color: #c0cc31;
  border-color: #020202;         
}     

.navbar-default {
   background-color: #c0cc31;
  border-color: #020202;         
}

.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #c0cc31;
  border-color: #020202;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: green;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffbbbc;
  background-color: #020202;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ffbbbc;
  background-color: #020202;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #020202;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #020202;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffbbbc;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ecf0f1;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffbbbc;
    background-color: #020202;
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: In your example CSS your first `navbar` rule is missing a period: `.navbar`. Otherwise works as expected.

Comment: Other than the missing `.`, this seems sound and works when I plug it into jsFiddle. It could be the ordering of your included css files. If you are including your site css file before the bootstrap css file, then your css can get overridden by bootstrap styles.

Comment: I fixed it. I don´t know why but I added the versions of bootstrap, which must have messed things up. Thank you anyway!